# Output from database ����

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding

I have the database filled with some data (added from command line), i setup encoding of the database to utf-8 as well as my website is.

But the output from the database where special chars like "š" etc. is outputted as "�", so what have I done wrong or what should I add? I am siply ECHOing as `echo $row['title'];` etc.

Comment: It is unclear what is your question. provide more information with code.

Comment: Could you try **utf8_decode($row['title']);** to see what you get?

Comment: Did you mean `utf8_encode($row['title'])`

Comment: We are guessing that when you added the data from the command line you did not ensure that the data you were inserting was in utf8 format first

Comment: Thanks utf8_encode works! :-)

Comment: `utf8_encode` should **not** be your preferred solution. Read the duplicate and **handle UTF-8 all the way through.**

Comment: @deceze Is right, that was just a suggestion to identify that your issue was that the load of the data was done incorrectly. Fix the data on the database rather than working around the mistake

Comment: Black diamonds usually means that you have non-utf8 bytes and failed to establish the connection with mysql correctly (see `mysqli_set_charset`).